# Blur input without calling Blur() function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, dom

I have angular custom input element. Now what I want to do is to blur this input programmatically using javascript. My special case is that I don't want to touch input itself. For instance, when I click some other document element on screen, input blurs, but when I call click() function on this dom element, it doesn't. So how can I blur it without touching input?

Comment: How can an input be blurred if it never had focus?

Comment: Who said that? It has focus

Comment: Ok. That information looked like it was omitted. Especially since the words “without touching the input” were used. — What’s the context of this? Are you running a test of some kind?

Comment: Maybe try using jquery on the client-side script. https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to blur your input without touching it, you need to focus an other element.

One could think that simply calling `focus()` on the default `document.activeElement` (`<body>`) would do, but it doesn't... 
Browsers [all differ](https://gist.github.com/TakayoshiKochi/0f658e372a1d382523bd) on this, and that's [one part of the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#data-model) I still struggle a lot to get my head off.

What all browsers agree on though is that an element with a `tabindex` != -1 attribute can be focused programmatically. So you could always set that attribute on the body of the document, that shouldn't change default focus behavior of your doc.

```js
document.body.tabIndex = 0;
document.querySelector( 'input' ).onfocus = (evt) => {
  console.log( 'will blur in 2s' );
  setTimeout( () => {
    console.log( 'blurring' );
    document.body.focus()
  }, 2000 );
};
```

```html
<input placeholder="click here to gain focus">
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear at the moment. You need to provide more code.

That said, you could use Angular [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) to blur or focus the input element. Try the following

Template

```html
<input #customInput type=text placeholder="Enter your name"/>

<button (mouseup)="blurInput(customInput)">Blur input</button>
<button (mouseup)="focusInput(customInput)">Focus input</button>
```

Here `customInput` is the template reference variable of the input element.

Controller

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  blurInput(input) {
    input.blur();
  }

  focusInput(input) {
    input.focus();
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mjdare)